# Widget Configuration Error: Widget's empty list widget is set to a non-existent component

Tags: flutter, widget, flutterflow

I have a flutterflow app.
I have a properties and addons table. Each addons has a reference to its associated Property.

The page I am currently having an error with is this page:
[Edit Addons Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPGRf.jpg)

I have a container, with a listview to display, the addons which are associated to the property.

I am currently getting this error
[Widget Configuration Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDPFb.png)

as you can see in the first picture, I have the backend query which hides the widget if no match.

I also have Conditional Visibility setup on the Container and listview:

[Conditional Visibility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLnKB.png)

I cant seem to figure out how to resolve this error, if anyone has any recommendations, I would greatly appreciate it.